# How to add an item to the todo list

Tags: reactjs, slice, setstate

This is a short cut of my addItem function in my todo app, i don't really understand what **slice** does in this ***value: this.state.newItem.slice()***. Can anybody explain me? Thank you so much!

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      newItem: "",
      list: []
    };

addItem() {
    // create a new item with unique id
    const newItem = {
      id: 1 + Math.random(),
  

    **value: this.state.newItem.slice()**

 
    };

    // copy current list of items
    const list = [...this.state.list];

    // add the new item to the list
    list.push(newItem);

    // update state with new list, reset the new item input
    this.setState({
      list,
      newItem: ""
    });
  }
```

Comment: freeCodeCamp has a really cool lesson on the .slice() function, check it out https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-data-structures/copy-array-items-using-slice

Comment: I think it's quite useless in this example, to slice a String object. Typically, to update state arrays in React (& Vue), the slice (different method, but similiar in function), map, concat & filter methods are used to return a brand new array, as mutating a state array may lead to errors. Nevertheless, it's not needed for String objects.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `slice` returns new string, the `slice` might have used to copy the string in the above code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Answer (score 0):

First of all why are you use slice method? If you used it to trim your value. you use The trim() method removes whitespace from both sides of a string. The trim() method does not change the original string. Syntax. string.trim().